# First-chance exception at (location) Access violation writing location

Tags: c

I have made a swap function in a program that needs to separate a string to 2 string. One for all the lower case letters and the other for all the upper case letters and I have got this error when debugging.

> Unhandled exception at 0x001C185B in upper_lower_letters.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x001C5865.

This is the function

```
void swapChars(char arr[], int index1, int index2)
{
    char aux = ' ';

    aux = arr[index1];
    arr[index1] = arr[index2];
    arr[index2] = aux;

}
```

And I get the error in this line

```
arr[index1] = arr[index2];
```

I call the function from this function

```
void sortLowerUpperCase(char str[])
{
    int i = 0, lowerC = 0, upperC = 0;
    int lowerIndexs[TH] = { 0 };
    int upperIndexs[TH] = { 0 };
    char lowerCaseStr[TH] = { 0 };
    char upperCaseStr[TH] = { 0 };

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            lowerIndexs[lowerC] = i;
            lowerC++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < lowerC; i++)
    {
        swapChars(str, lowerIndexs[i], i);
    }

    strcpy(lowerCaseStr, str);

    puts(lowerCaseStr);
}
```

In the main I call the `sortLowerUpperCase` like this

```
sortLowerUpperCase("LiDoR");
```

This is the value of the variables in the debug window:

[image]

So it's now going out of the bounds of the array. 
What can I do for make it work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: sounds like you are going out of bounds on the array.  Make sure `lowerIndexs[i]` and `i` are inside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Check which elements are being accessed. You may be accessing an element with a null.

Comment: First `C` is not `C++`, so please choose a tag.  Second, we need to know what arguments you're calling your `sortLowerUpperCase` function with.  If the argument is a string-literal, your program exhibits undefined behavior since string-literals cannot be modified.

Comment: I can't confirm without more information - specifically, how the function's being called - but it's possible you're trying to modify strings that are in read-only memory. If you call `swapChars("Hello world", 0, 1);` it's likely to crash with your error because `"Hello world"` is usually stored in read-only memory - it's a string literal.

Comment: yeah i fixed that thanks antiduh i called the sortLowerUpperCase function with a read only string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main` function, replace the call to `sortLowerUpperCase("LiDoR");`

with

```
char * string = (char *)malloc(6);
strcpy(string, "LiDoR");
sortLowerUpperCase(string);
```

**Reason**

In C, string literals are created in a read-only area of the memory on most architecture. Later, when you try to write / replace some part of that string literal (in the statements `arr[index1] = arr[index2];` and `arr[index2] = aux;`) which is in the read-only memory section, you obviously get this error (seg fault). So to avoid accidentally writing memory to read-only section, you should create memory on your own (either using `malloc` or using an array) and then copy the string literal to that memory.